# iPhone - How to create a scrolling UIToolbar above keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitoolbar

How do you create a scrolling `UIToolbar`, the one with extra accessory buttons above keyboard that is also scrollable through its width? Like Day One and Byword did.

**Edit**: I'm using in `UITextView`

From Byword

[image]

This is what I have done with my input accessory view, I had already implemented the bar button items. Now I curious if I could make it scroll horizontally to reveal more buttons.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a UITextField or UITextView?

Comment: I'm using UITextView of course

Answer (score 5):

Use this code in viewDidLoad:

```
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done:)],nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
self.yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

This basically adds a toolbar on the keyboard with a bar button that reads "Done".

Answer (score 5):

Create one view which contains your all buttons within scrollview and assign that view as inputAccessoryView or you TextField. Hope you will get my ans.

Answer (score 4):

Create number of bar buttons based on your requirement and add them to an array.
Now create a scrollview inside an view. And give the scrollview as an input accessory view to text field.

Here is an example :
1. Create bar buttons based on your requirement

```
UIBarButtonItem* button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(done:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* button3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(done:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* button4 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(done:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* button5 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRedo target:self action:@selector(done:)];
```

2. Add them to an array

   ```
    NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,nil];
   ```
3. Create a scrollview inside an UIView

   ```
   UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
   scrollView.frame = toolbar.frame;
   scrollView.bounds = toolbar.bounds;
   scrollView.autoresizingMask = toolbar.autoresizingMask;
   scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true;
   scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true;
   scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

   //scrollView.bounces = false;
   UIView *superView = toolbar.superview;
   [toolbar removeFromSuperview];
   toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
   toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, toolbar.frame.size.height);
   toolbar.bounds = toolbar.frame;
   [toolbar setItems:itemsArray];
   scrollView.contentSize = toolbar.frame.size;
   [scrollView addSubview:toolbar];
   [superView addSubview:scrollView];
   ```
4. Add the scrollview as `inputAccessoryView` to textField

   self.textField.inputAccessoryView = scrollView;

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass UIView and add a UIToolbar as background view.
Add UIScrollView inside it add Add UIButtons in this UIScrollView. Ex:

```
@implementation CustomAccessoryView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        // Make toolbar as faked background
        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        [toolbar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

        [self addSubview:toolbar];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:toolbar]; 

        //Insert UIScrollVIew as subview and add button inside it

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

while begin aditing text you should set uiview animation.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
CGRect rect=self.view.frame;
rect.origin.y=-50;
self.view.frame=rect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

after end editing then

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
CGRect rect=self.view.frame;
rect.origin.y=0;
self.view.frame=rect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```